# Checking for reference entity being null in Select(...) projects all columns in generated SQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

When checking a many to one entity reference for null in a LINQ to NHibernate query projection all of the table columns of the table associated with that entity are being projected.

For example: having an entity Review which has a many to one reference member User, when projecting the following:

```
.Select(review => new
{
    ShowPhoto = review.User == null ? false : review.User.ShowPhoto
})
```

or

```
.Select(review => new
{
    ShowPhoto = review.User != null && review.User.ShowPhoto
})
```

the generated SQL is projecting all of the columns of User table (it should only project ShowPhoto column based on this example).

My question is what would be a solution for avoiding this unneeded selection of all of the columns (as it could be quite inefficient in many cases)?

Comment: You may have to write a bit of LINQ or QueryOver to select *only* the column you want. NHibernate is going to load the entire `User` into memory when you access a single property on it. You might also be able to control this a little bit via the various lazy loading settings in the mapping, but I'm not positive.

Comment: The `.Select(...)` is part of the LINQ to NHibernate query so it depends on NHibernate on how it wants to translate the projection AST to SQL. The proxy rules should not apply at all as there is no entity hydrated at that point, it is just the description of what to query. I got an idea of how to check for null using a subquery instead of != or == null but will have to check it later.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I found so far is to also map the many to one as a property with Update(false):

Entity:

```
public virtual UserAccount User { get; set; }
public virtual int? UserID { get; protected set; }
```

Mapping:

```
ManyToOne(x => x.User, mapper => mapper.Column("UserAccountID"));
Property(x => x.UserID, mapper =>
{
    mapper.Column("UserAccountID");
    mapper.Update(false);
});
```

And then query using:

```
.Select(review => new
{
    ShowPhoto = review.UserID.HasValue && review.User.ShowPhoto
})
```

*Ignore the bellow method:*

One verbose/hacky solution would be to use a subquery:

```
.Select(review => new
{
    ShowPhoto = reviewManager.Query().Any(r => r.Id == review.Id && r.User != null) && review.User.ShowPhoto
})
```